# How to set navigation properties that are collections using a collection of ids

Tags: entity-framework

I have just spent a couple of hours on this problem, and I would like to simplify it in future because I can see it being a common requirement.

I have a Question class with a navigation property that is a collection:

```
public class AnsweredQuestion : ModelBase
{  
    public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }  
}
```

All my models inherit a single base class:

```
public abstract class ModelBase
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to set the Answers collection from a collection of answer ids and I have this method in my controller - and it does work

```
    private void SetAnswers(AnsweredQuestion question, 
                            IEnumerable<int> newAnswerIDs)
    {
        //First remove any answers we don't want
        question.Answers.RemoveAll(a => !newAnswerIDs.Contains(a.ID));

        //Then project the current ids
        IEnumerable<int> currentAnswerIds = question.Answers.Select(a => a.ID);

        //Now go to the database to get the answers that match the ids that 
        //we have to add
        IQueryable<Answer> answersToAdd = _uow.AnswerRepository.All                            
                 .Where(dbAnswers => newAnswerIDs.Contains(dbAnswers.ID) 
                                   &&
                                   !currentAnswerIds.Contains(dbAnswers.ID));

        //and add them to the navigation property  
        question.Answers.AddRange(answersToAdd);
    }
```

But this code is quite complicated, and I can see me having to write it again and again in each Model where I have a navigation property.

If this was a 1 to many relationship I'd have an Answer property and an AnswerID property in my entity and the framework would resolve the issue for me. But, as far as I know, I cant do that for many to many relationships.

Can anyone think of a way to turn this into a method that can be called on any navigation property in any model? I thought about creating an extension method on a collection of models, but my stumbling block is that I need to go to the database to get the Answers that match the ids I have before I add them to the Answers collection and that would mean that my extension method would need to know which repository to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have come up with:

```
public static bool SetById<T>(this ICollection<T> collection,
    IEnumerable<int> ids,
    IRepository<T> repo)
where T : ModelBase
{
    //First remove any answers we don't want
    int count = collection.Count;
    collection.RemoveAll(a => !ids.Contains(a.ID));
    bool isAltered = count != collection.Count;

    //Then project the current ids
    IEnumerable<int> currentIds = collection.Select(a => a.ID);

    IQueryable<T> toAdd = repo.All.Where(dbAnswers => ids.Contains(dbAnswers.ID) && !currentIds.Contains(dbAnswers.ID));
    isAltered = isAltered || toAdd.Any();

    //and add them to the navigation property
    collection.AddRange(toAdd);

    return isAltered;
}
```

This is dependent on all my entities inheriting from a base class with an ID:

```
public abstract class ModelBase
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

And in my controller I call it like this (passing in my repository):

```
    question.Answers.SetById(newAnswerIDs, _uow.AnswerRepository);
```