# In entity framework I have an id (int) that collect the id for the other class. How to convert it from class to id?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The following information, the classes that end with -Values are the entities to save to database. The end with -Parameter are classes for business logic calculation.

```
public class SampleValues // this is a entity that i want to collect the deatil id
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int[] SampleDetailIdValue { get; set; }
}

public class SampleDetailValues // this is the detail entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class SampleParameter // this is a class that i will use for the business logic
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SampleDetailValues[] SampleDetail { get; set; }
    public double { get; set; }
}

public class SampleDetailParameter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is I want to convert the id in the SampleDetailValues[] to save to the database. How to do that?

If there is unclear point, please let me know.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Mapping CLASSES to db tables is the whole point of an ORM. Why are you trying to undermine this concept? What are you trying to do? It doesn't look very clean, to be honest.

Comment: The unclean that you mention is 'why i convert database value to a new class, right? one reason (it has other reasons that i am not sure) behind this is I want to separate the business and database layer in a different thread. I do MVVM for this project.

Comment: So you initially have an array of ints and want to store it in the db? (I understood it the other way 'round...)

Comment: Yes. I want to store the id from the detail classes.

Comment: Only the id? Your corresponding business logic class ('SampleDetailValues ' <-> 'SampleDetailParameter', right?) has some more values. Taken that into account, this looks like a regular 1:n relationship. Please add the db model to your question to clarify.

Comment: Yes, it is 1:n relationship. which db model you want(I really don't know what exactly model to add). It like a 'in 1 sample master can has many simple details'. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: I mean: a diagram of the involved db tables.

Comment: How to set navigation properties that are collections using a collection of ids: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17110278/150342

Comment: @ThomasWeller Sorry, I cannot show it.

Comment: user3089631 Then it is not possible to answer your question...

Answer (score 0):

If you cant/wont model as

```
public class SampleDetailValues // this is the detail entity
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
}

// typically done with a join table, since arrays cant be modelled to scalar DB types
public class SampleParameterIds
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SampleParameterName {get;set}
    public int DetailId { get; set; } 

    [ForeignKey("DetailId")]
    public virtual SampleDetailValues detailValue {get; Set;}          
    [ForeignKey("SampleParamaterName")]
    public virtual SampleParamter sampleParameter {get; Set;}          

}

public class SampleParameter // this is a class that i will use for the business logic
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
//   public SampleDetailValues[] SampleDetail { get; set; } // see join table 
    public double { get; set; }
}
```

**then try** 
Using a string that you "manage" with the correct values.  the array can be `join`-ed to make a string and split to fill the array. BUT you and not EF must manage the content

```
public class SampleDetailValues // this is the detail entity
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
}


public class SampleParameter // this is a class that i will use for the business logic
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SampleDetailIds {get;Set;} // you should convert array to string and back...eg join/split
    public SampleDetailValues[] SampleDetail { get; set; } // ef should ignore this type as it is invalid on Db.
    public double { get; set; }
}
```